# Both [gmail] and [gmail-api] tags look to be about the Gmail RESTful API. What should be done to properly tag questions related to Gmail?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

[gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail) (6,585 questions) and [gmail-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail-api) (1,652 questions) both claim to be for questions about the RESTful API. There are other tags about Gmail but I think that we need other tags:

- to be used with bookmarklets / users scripts
- to be used with [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) for questions about the GmailApp service, not the Gmail Advanced Service which use the GMail API. ([[google-apps-script] gmailapp](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20gmailapp) returns 156 questions).

Other existing tags that include `gmail` (referring to Gmail):

- [gmail-imap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail-imap) (468 questions)
- [gmail-pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail-pop) (41 questions)

So,

- Should the [gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail) tag be made a synonym of [gmail-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail-api), or the [gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail) tag excerpt and wiki be edited, or new tags should be created?
- Should questions with [gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail) tag and [imap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imap) tag (437 questions)  be edited to add [gmail-imap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail-imap)?

---

If we keep [gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail), I think that we should include on the tag excerpt and wiki that non-programming questions are off-topic on SO and that those questions could be asked on any other places like - but not limited to - http://superuser.com, http://webapps.stackexchange.com, http://security.stackexchange.com, http://serverfault.com, the Google Products Help Forum, the Google Cloud Connect community site, among other places.

Comment: I always thought [Gmail] was for general use, without the API, borderline a meta-tag, e.g. "*How do I check Gmail's POP3 in c#?*"... But this is the first time I read the tag wiki.

Comment: @Mariano Gmail questions aren't on topic on SO.

Comment: @Braiam: What makes you think that?

Comment: @Rubén I think Braiam means general Gmail Questions (Non api related) which are indeed off topic imho. Mail Protocol question shouldn't be tagged by a specific provider for example.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Thank's. Regarding the second part in your comment, do you have or are you thinking about a suggestion regarding what to do with [tag:gmail], [tag:gmail-api] or the questions that include these tags? (:

Comment: @Rubén Maybe retagging everything with [`email`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email) wich belongs to general email programming and closing everything that is offtopic. Then make one tag the synonym of another. I would prefer `gmail-api`.

Comment: That is feasible I think, but what about questions about bookmarklets and users scripts, [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) and other programming questions related to Gmail but not to [tag:gmail-api].

Comment: Yeah not thought about this. Not sure if a question about a [userscript] needs to have a [gmail] (Imho it would be meta tag). For a app, I would propose a [gmail-app] instead. But ofcourse I am not sure about all that.

Answer (score 4):

The [gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail) tag excerpt and wiki **should be edited**. Make them more general but clearly state that **non-programming questions are off-topic** for this site.

Answer (score 1):

The [gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail) tag should **be made a synonym** of [gmail-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail-api)