# What to do with tags related to email service providers (gmail, outlook, hotmail, yahoo, ...)?

Tags: discussion, tags

This question is derived from [`gmail` and `gmail-api` tags look to be both about the Gmail RESTful API. What should be done to properly tag questions related to Gmail?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348038/1595451), more specifically from the comments around the fact that we not do general (non-programming) help / support about using email services like Gmail, Outlook.com, Yahoo Mail, etc.

Should we refine the tag excerpt / wikis of email services related questions, burninate them or make the synonyms of the corresponding API related tag?

---

Related tags

- [gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail) (6,589 questions) <sup>1</sup>
- [outlook.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook.com), [hotmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hotmail) (446 questions)
- [yahoo-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-mail) (119 questions)

What have in common

- The above tags collectively are not on the top tags. ([This search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail+or+outlook.com+or+hotmail+or+yahoo-mail?sort=newest&pageSize=15) returns 7,079 questions)
- Their tags excerpts and wikis doesn't describe how the they should be used.

API related tags

- [gmail-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail-api) (1,656 questions) <sup>1</sup>
- [outlookrest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlookrest-api) (303 questions) <-- [outlook-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-api) (33 questions)
- [yahoo-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-api) (655 questions)

> <sup>1</sup> Note: As previously was mentioned, already discussed on [`gmail` and `gmail-api` tags look to be both about the Gmail RESTful API. What should be done to properly tag questions related to Gmail?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348038/1595451)

Other related tags

- [email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email), [pop3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop3), [imap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imap), [smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smtp), [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns), [html-email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-email)

Related questions

- [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/1595451)
- [Off-topic: "My email isn't spam"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302903/1595451)